# Parsing Data From JSON To Windows Form

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I am retrieving JSON from a web service and am getting this error:

> Error CS0030  Cannot convert type 'PokeForm.MoveInformation' to 'PokeForm.Move'

This is the code I am using to query the web service and the classes I use to parse the data into the format I need:

```
private void GrabData()
{
    WebClient syncClient = new WebClient();
    string url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/lucario/";
    string response = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

    var bl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PokeAPI[]>(response);
    foreach (PokeAPI ro in bl)
    {
        if (ro.Moves != null)
        {
            foreach (MoveInformation mi in ro.Moves)
            {
                Move mv = mi.Move;
                MessageBox.Show(mv.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class PokeAPI
{
    public List<MoveInformation> Moves { get; set; }
}
public class MoveInformation
{
    public Move Move { get; set; }
}
public class Move
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

What needs to be changed in my `foreach` loop so that the data will display as I desire?

**EDIT**
I edited my syntax to the below per the answer

```
foreach (MoveInformation mi in ro.Moves)
{
  Move mv = mi.Move;
  MessageBox.Show(mv.Name);
}
```

And now I get this run-time error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'PokeForm.PokeAPI[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

This is the JSON - https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/lucario/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PokeAPI.Moves` is a `List<MoveInformation>` not a `List<Move>`.  So your inner `foreach` needs to be:

```
foreach (MoveInformation mi in ro.Moves)
{
    Move mv = mi.Move;
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

The runtime error means that you are trying to deserialize into an array but the JSON represents a single object.

Change your code to this:

```
var ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PokeAPI>(response);
if (ro.Moves != null)
{
    foreach (MoveInformation mi in ro.Moves)
    {
        Move mv = mi.Move;
        MessageBox.Show(mv.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: See my edit - I made change you suggest, but am now getting a run-time error

Comment: Edit your question to show the JSON and the code you are using to deserialize it.   I don't have enough information to diagnose the error.  If I had to guess, I would say you are deserializing into a PokeAPI array, but the JSON represents a single object.

Comment: Thanks! Added a link to the JSON that is being returned as well as the full method of how I am querying the data

Comment: OK, yes, that is the problem.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if the PokeAPI is a list it should like this:

```
var ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PokeAPI>(response);
```

then ro is the list of PokeAPi class